# How to recursively shift `<user_id>`:`<group_id>` by a specific value using `xargs` or `exec`

Tags: ubuntu, xargs, exec

I'm trying to recursively shift `<user_id>`:`<group_id>` by a specific value using `xargs` or `exec`. I'm having difficulty with passing output from `find` to variable with `stat` function. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

```
find . -type f,d | xargs chown $(($(stat --printf %u {})+1)):$(($(stat --printf %g {})+1)) {}
```

`stat: cannot stat '{}': No such file or directory`

`stat: cannot stat '{}': No such file or directory`

`chown: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `zsh` here:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
# enable the stat builtin (which btw predates GNU stat by several years)
zmodload zsh/stat || exit

# enable chown (and other file manipulation builtin)
zmodload zsh/files || exit
ret=0

for f (./**/*(DN.,/) .) {
  stat -LH s $f && # store file attributes in the $s hash/associative array
    chown $((s[uid] + 1)):$((s[gid] + 1)) $f || ret=$?
}
exit $ret # report any error in stat()ing or chown()ing files
```

(where `D` for dotfile is to include hidden files, `N` for nullglob is to not consider it an error if no file is found `.,/` is regular or directory like `-type f,d`).

If on a GNU system like your Ubuntu 20.04, you could also do:

```
find . -type f,d -printf '%p\0%U\0%G\0' | # print path, uid, gid as 3
                                          # nul-delimited records
  gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{
    file = $0; getline uid; getline gid
    print (uid+1) ":" (gid+1); print file}' | # outputs a uid+1:gid+1
                                              # and path record for each file
  xargs -r0n2 chown # pass each pair of record to chown
```

But as that involves running one `chown` per file (in the `zsh` approach, we were running the `chown` builtin in the `zsh/files` module), that's going to be a lot less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It actually working. Could you please, describe for better understanding what each line of the code is doing / What's actually going on?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find . -type f,d |
  parallel 'chown $(($(stat --printf %u {})+1)):$(($(stat --printf %g {})+1)) {}'
```